# Exit of GridSearchCV processing connect with scoring value

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm using `GridSearchCV` to found the best degree of `PolynomialFeature` based on **MSE** returned from `LinearRegression()`.

Before `GridSearchCV` , I first used a loop which was stopped when **MSE** is >10K.
How could I implement the same kind  of *"exit loop"* with `GridSearchCV()` for the sake of time optimisation?

```
skf2 = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=4, train_size = 0.8,random_state =63)
start = time.time()

poly_linear = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures()),
                      ('Linear', LinearRegression(fit_intercept =False))])

parameters = {'poly__degree': [1,2,3,4,5]}

grid_search_lin = GridSearchCV(poly_linear, parameters, cv=skf2, n_jobs=-1, scoring='mean_squared_error').fit(X_l, Y_l)
print('timer',time.time() - start,'s')
```

Comment: Please clarify more. How have you `"I first used a loop which was stopped when MSE is >10K"`, before GridSearchCV?

Comment: I simply used a `for` loop with an `break` condition  where , at each iteration, I check if a the **MSE** of my modele is > 10K:
    `for i in range(len(degree)):
        Xp= PolynomialFeature(i).fit_transform(X)
        mse = abs(np.mean(cross_val_score(regp, Xp, Y, cv = skf, scoring = 'mean_squared_error', n_jobs= -1)))
        if mse >= 10000:
            break`

Answer (score 0):

`GridSearchCV` is an exhaustive search, i.e. it considers **all** the parameters given (`[1,2,3,4,5]`). I'm not aware of the possibility of an *exit loop* with GridSearchCV.
If time is an issue, you could either (1) decrease the space of your params grid, (2) decrease the number of cv iterations (managed by `n_splits` in `skf2`), (3) use `RandomizedSearchCV` to randomly pick parameters from your grid. Neither is a good option in terms of model selection quality, but it will take less time anyways.

Also, not sure why you're not fitting an intercept. Unless there is a specific reason for that, you'd better fit a regression with an intercept as it will reduce model bias.

Hope this helps

Comment: For the `fit_intercept` I heard that, in machine learning it would be better to set it false .
I'm thinking about using joblib multiprocessing in a way where I could checking `grid_search.cv_results` during  the process and stop it , is my condition is verified .

Comment: @lelchim Can't really advise on stopping upon a condition with multiprocessing, but as far as for `fit_intercept` -- generally there is no reason to believe that the hyperplane you're trying to approximate with `LinearRegression` should go through the origin (i.e. no intercept), thus, fitting the intercept is preferred.